# Помогите с sys.stdin,пожалуйста

Tags: python

```
import sys

with open('people-file.txt') as f:
    raws_quantity = len(f.read().split('\n'))

file = open('people-file.txt', encoding = "utf-8")
sys.stdin = file

for x in range(raws_quantity):
    print(input())
choice = input('y/n ')
```

Выходит ошибка EOFError: EOF when reading a line,что неудивительно,ведь python думает,что я хочу прочесть
ещё одну строку из файла,но как ему сказать,что я просто запрашиваю пользовательский ввод?
sys.stdin.close() и file.close() я пробовал,теперь уже он ругается на операцию на закрытый файл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys
with open('people-file.txt') as f:
    raws_quantity=len(f.read().split('\n'))
file=open('people-file.txt',encoding="utf-8")
sys.stdin=file
for x in range(raws_quantity - 1):
    print(input())
sys.stdin = sys.__stdin__
choice=input('yes or no? ')
```

Comment: это тоже не помогает

Comment: RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stdin

Comment: @Someone у меня всё работает. Тестирую тут https://repl.it/repls/CanineThirdScience

Comment: действительно работает

Comment: только на сайте

Comment: @Someone здесь тоже всё работает, так что проблема у вас https://onlinegdb.com/S1IfbEZ6U

Comment: мой файл существует,но sys.__stdin__ возвращает None,на сайте возвращает <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdin>' mode='r' encoding='utf-8'>

Comment: @Someone скорее всего поэтому "Note Under some conditions stdin, stdout and stderr as well as the original values __stdin__, __stdout__ and __stderr__ can be None. It is usually the case for Windows GUI apps that aren’t connected to a console and Python apps started with pythonw."

Comment: @Someone из документации https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html

Comment: @Someone в таком случае просто явно сохраняйте предыдущее значение в какой-нибудь объект и восстанавливайте его далее

Comment: спасибо за помощь,я просто записал значение sys.stdin в переменную в самом начале

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('people-file.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = f.read()

for line in data:
    print(line)

choice = input('yes or no? ')
```

Comment: Смешно,но мне нужен именно sys.stdin,я знаю,что так можно сделать очень легко,но я не использую этот код,мне это нужно в другом коде,а сам пример я выбрал как самый лёгкий,мне просто нужно знать,возможно ли заставить интерпретатор реагировать реагировать на input() как на пользовательский ввод после использования sys.stdin

Comment: @Someone приведите целевой код и задачу. Абстракция через другие примеры не помогает никому.